# most_common with django-taggit

Tags: django, django-taggit

I'm trying to get an ordered list of the most-used tags on my site. The [API docs](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit/blob/master/docs/api.txt) for django taggit reference a most_common() method, but I can't seem to make it work. Docs say:

"Returns a `QuerySet` of all tags, annotated with the number of times they appear, available as the `num_times` attribute on each tag."

But they don't show a working example. Assuming that an "Item" model has a working "tags" field, does this mean you should be able to do something like:

```
Item.objects.all.tags.most_common()
```

I've tried variations of this but can't seem to get an ordered list of most-used tags. What's the magic incantation expected here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe it should be without the `objects.all`:

```
tags = Item.tags.most_common()
```

Comment: Also, I'm curious how you figured that out from the API docs, if you don't mind a quick explainer.

Comment: `tags` is a TaggableManager object, which is a subclass of a [Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/). It works the same way as `objects`, so typical usage is `ModelClass.manager_instance.query_modification_method()`